# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' plot graph

Tags: python

I have this data as a csv

```
Group | Man | Women

0 to 4|10000|20000
5 to 9|20000|50000
...
80+   |100  |4000
```

and a need to plot a bar graph, but when define the x and y and put the code `plt.plot(x,y)`

python returs the error `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`,

how can I resolve?

Comment: please give [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = pd.read_csv(files_path + '   .csv', sep=';', header=0)

x = file[['Group']]
y = file[['Men']]

plt.barh(x, y)
plt.show( )

Comment: it seems typo. y = file[['Men']] in your code, but the csv is "Man".

Answer (score 0):

You can write to make bar chart with matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', sep=';', header=0)
plt.barh(file["Group"].tolist(), file["Men"].tolist())
plt.show()
```

or the below as alternative:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', sep=';', header=0)
ax = file.plot.barh(x='Group', y='Women')
plt.show()
```